# Unable to upload images into the media library

Tags: uploads

After moving my website from one host to another I am unable to upload new pictures in my media library either by directly using the Media > Add New menu or by adding media from within the new post editor.

The weird thing is that it seems that the upload was successful as I can see the image being added into the media library and even the correct image size and path is being displayed but instead of the preview image I get a blank white image as shown in this image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYDML.jpg

When checking the actual path of my website I don't see the ../2020/04/ folder being created or the image  anywhere to be found. If I manually create the path and upload the image using ftp while also setting the correct folder permissions and ownership ( /var/www/hlbenefits.com/html/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/medicalDisclaimer ), I still cannot see the preview image in the media library but the image is accessible for viewing or editing here:

- https://www.hlbenefits.com/medicaldisclaimer/
- https://www.hlbenefits.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=205158&action=edit

Please note that:

- I can successfully upload other files such as theme or plugin files
  to my WordPress website.
- I can see and use other old images.
- Other websites hosted on the same host do not have this issue.

What I have done so far:

- I have completely disabled all plugins and themes and applied the
  default Twenty Nineteen theme.
- Double checked the folder permissions and ownership
- Completely disabled cloudflare for
  this website.
- Activated the wordpress debug mode and observed the log
  file in real time.
- Installed Site Health and applied the recommended
  improvements so right now I only need to remove inactive plugins and
  themes.
- Tried saving the Permalink Settings as suggested by other wordpress members

My wordpress configuration as shown by the Site Health plugin is as follows:

I tried to add here the output of the Site Health plugin but my quested was marked as spam and there was no other way to correct this but to delete the whole output. Please see the wordpress forums link below.

What I find weird is the uploads_size: 10.18 MB (10671247 bytes) that's inaccurate as my uploads folder is way bigger than this and I've noticed that in my initial post on the wordpress forums - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/unable-to-view-newly-uploaded-images/ - , the Site Health output showed 0 bytes so this is somehow related or the Site Health plugin doesn't correctly report the size.

Comment: How did you move your site? Sometimes problem arises after moving. Did you try to setup a new website as a subdomain to test? So that it could compare and confirm that under same domain have same problem or not.

Comment: I have installed a fresh wordpress and restored from a UpdraftPlus backup. Didn't tried  the subdomain website but I did moved other websites using the same method on this host and they don't seem to have this issue.

Comment: did UpdraftPlus replace the domain for you in DB? Because Duplicator will do that, I am not sure if UpdraftPlus will do it for you. It sounds like there is path translation problem to me.

Comment: @simongcc Even if not exactly the solution, your answer helped a lot in identifying the culprit. It was the Settings > Media > Store uploads in this folder value that I needed to upload in order to show the correct uploads path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @simongcc and https://fancythemes.com/fix-image-upload-issue-wordpress I've found that the  `Settings > Media > Store uploads in this folder` value was not correct and after updating with the correct path I was able to successfully upload pictures.

Comment: It is great that you have resolved the issue. And it is my pleasure to share the experience. :)